# How to secure sensitive informations in settings.py

Tags: python, django, dotenv

I have some sensitive information about MySql, celery, and redis in my settings.py. I read that its better to keep them in an `.env` file with `python-dotenv` or keep them in the linux's environment variables. But I am confused in this point. Even if they are in a separate file like `.env` or in environment variables they are still plain text.

Is there way to keep them encrypted in a file or environment variable and make django possible to read them ? I don't want them to be plain text in somewhere.

Comment: If someone has enough access to read the env vars, you have bigger problems. If you encrypted them, you'd also have to have the code to decrypt them on the same machine, so you haven't really gained anything.

Comment: Yes, they are plain text. But who has access to that plain text? You're not going to check those files into the code repository, that's the point of putting them into separate files or environment variables. They only exist on the specific production server. And anyone who has access to *that*, where the code which needs those values will be running too, has access to the values whether you encrypt them or not.

Comment: .ENV files is a best practice in keeping sensitive informations. The point is that you can store that file outside the django application directory, so it is not reacheable in any way through HTTP. Also be sure that files are readeable only by Django user (chmod). You can encrypt the variables, but in that case.. where will you store the private key or password? in plain text?

Comment: A customer warned us about keeping this plain text secrets as environment variable ad want me to keep them encrypted. I'm confused now. What is difference keeping them in a file with django-environ or in environment variable if both are in plain text. If someone has access to the server. He can access both if keep them plain text right?